# How to use more then one language in android speech recognition at the same time

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

All we know that many languages includes several words from other languages. While using android speech recognition (Androdi4.1) to develop an android application, we need that app  process the speech input with two languages (EN and TR) at the same time (or asynch) and bring us both of the results.

English word "Burger" in Turkish pronunciation is  "Börgır" .
If we use android speech recognition in english, application understands Burger as Burger 
(on text) .
If we use android speech recognition in turkish, application understands Burger as Börgır(on text)
This is because Turkish language is written as spoken.

For example:

speech recognition result with Turkish option: **Börgır** yemek istiyorum

speech recognition result with English option: **Burger** xxxxx yyyyyyyyy

Expected result is(with combined result) : Burger yemek istiyorum

So do you know how to process two languages at the same time , with android speech recognition to collect both results, after that we will combine them in order to get best results.

Below code is used for implementing android speech recognition within application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

// Specify the calling package to identify your application

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "tr"); --- or eng-us
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you pick one language for the speech recognizer like english. Then when you speak your other language, see what the speech recognizer comes up with. You may be able to interpret the english recognition of that.

For example, if you want to speak spanish to the english recognizer and the user says "si" in spanish, you might notice the recognizer recognizes that as "see"

Comment: If we can not find any solution with current API's, interpreting was an answer for us as yours. As Kaarel said there are no current solution we will move on yours and ours solution,thank you

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done using the current Android APIs.

You could try to run two instances of [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) at the same time (one with a Turkish `EXTRA_LANGUAGE`, the other with English). This will probably not work because different services cannot use the microphone at the same time.

You could try to implement the recording part yourself and then push the resulting byte array to two different recognizers. But there is no API for that.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it like that:

> ```
>    language = "tr-TR";
> ```

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, language);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, language);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS, language);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: it does not solve the problem, did you try it on offline mode

Comment: offline mode? How to reach google api when ethernet off. I guess, it is impossible